# How do you re-try a try after you've handled an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Say you have a TRY block. I try to write to a file but the file doesn't exist so it throws an exception.

```
try
{
     TryWritingToFile();          
}
catch (Exception)
{
     CreateFile();
     //now I want to go back and try to write to the file again. 
}
```

How do I go back to the beginning of the try block? Do I need to "re-try" in the catch block? Isn't this repeating code?

Comment: why not just have this as a method which you run at the end of `CreateNewFile`?

Comment: Could also use a goto !SHOCK HORROR!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool ok = false; 

while(!ok)
{    
    try
    {
        TryWritingToFile();          
        ok = true; 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        CreateFile();
        //now I want to go back and try to write to the file again. 
    }
}
```

Comment: this is something along the lines of what im looking to do, though im not sure how id handle the infinite loop, as @gdoron mentioned.

Comment: @Testifier you could use a catch(undesired exceptions) {break; or throw;} and catch(ignored exceptions) {} to fix the infinite loop problem.

Comment: @tcannon91 To *possibly fix* .. of course the ignored exception could happen indefinitely .. I recommend a countdown or timer if this pattern is *ever* used.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I go back to the beginning of the try block?

**You can't**, but you can call the same function again- recursion.

Note that catching the global `Exception` exception isn't considered to be best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need an exception filter for the general case of retrying the operation from the exact point where the exception occurred, which .NET supports, but C# doesn't.  Use VB.NET, F#, or C++/CLI.  Or maybe MSIL.

And I'm not quite sure what the .NET equivalent is to returning `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` in an exception filter expression.

---

The reason this has to be done in an exception filter is that exception filters are evaluated during first-chance exception handling, while the call stack is still intact.  By the time a catch block is executed during second-chance exception handling, stack unwinding has already begun and there's no way to resume execution of a call frame that's no longer on the call stack.

Comment: Even in vb.net, where exception filters run before stack unwinding, there is no supported means to resume execution from the point where the exception was thrown.  Among other things, compilers will often assume that code which follows an unconditional `throw` cannot be executed under any circumstances and thus need not be compiled.  It would be impossible to successfully have execution continue with code which does not exist.

Comment: @supercat: .NET exceptions ARE Win32 structured exceptions.  So you could still have a native SEH filter somewhere in the call tree resume execution in the middle of managed code.  Futhermore, the values for the [`endfilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.endfilter.aspx) opcode match exactly with the native SEH values.  I wonder what happens if you push -1 (`EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`) instead of the documented values...

Comment: If you'd like to try that out, I'd be curious about what would happen.  Does CIL throw exceptions using an opcode that's designed for that purpose?  Perhaps the JIT inserts a "jmp  ReallyHorribleFatalError" following the "trigger exception" code?  There are some advantages to exception filtering, and I consider C#'s lack of them to be a weakness.  Personally, I think that while C++ exception handling was an improvement over what came before, I strongly dislike the notion of using the type of the exception object as the means for deciding whether an exception should be caught.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to catch some specific File I/O exceptions here rather than the base class Exception.

Why not wrap the whole code block in a while loop checking a bool of some sort which is set on success?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this sort of affect with any number of complicated tricks, such as:

```
bool success = false;
while(!success)
{
    try
    {
        WriteToFile();
        success = true;
    }
    catch()
    {
        CreateFile();
    }
}
```

But they're all problematic, and should be avoided at all costs.  The control flow is less-than-obvious, and there are often additional downsides. The above code is a good recipe for an infinite loop, for example.

The root of the problem in situations like these is usually that you're using exceptions as a control flow mechanism. For example, here you're relying on exceptions to tell you if the file exists or not.  That's problematic because exceptions break control flow and come with performance penalties.  A better option is to rearrange the code so that you're not relying on exceptions to communicate anything but exceptional situations.  There's almost always a more direct (and more efficient) way to figure out what the exception is telling you.

For example:

```
if(!CheckFileExists()) CreateFile();
WriteToFile();
```

Comment: Even better: `CreateFileIfNotPresent(); WriteToFile();`